# Want to use flyway to migrate ETL changes

Tags: flyway

We use a process to migrate our ETL changes, but not the associated SQL code that often need to be applied to both the source and target DBs.  Is there a way for us to specify which SQL files get applied to which DB?

Answer (score 0):

Use one Flyway instance per DB and set a different location to load the sql files from for each DB. You can also specify a common one for both.